# Red Font (In Firefox) <img> tags in HTML not seen by JSoup

Tags: html, css, firefox, jsoup

EDIT: Self-Answered. JSoup does indeed find all image tags.

I'm trying to scrape something off https://www.flickr.com/explore and I ran into a problem.

In the source code, the main images on that website are written in red font, and they don't get found by my JSoup `select` method (or with the `getElementsByTag` method). It would be much easier if you guys went to the website and checked the source code yourself because of formatting issues but I'll try to include the bare minimum here.

**EDIT:** I just tried viewing the source code through chrome and IE, and the image tags are not red, so I'm assuming it's firefox formatting. But the question remains, JSoup doesn't see those image tags. (Second edit at the end of the post)

**EDIT 3:** Removed my pasted code to put this print screen in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSAip.png[image: source code]
Notice how the red blocks are the main user uploaded images (that I want), and you can see other img tags that are not red (but those are only things like tiny logos). When I run the code

```
Elements imageElements = doc.select("img");
```

and then print it, I get all the  tags that are not red.

I'm not very experienced with HTML or CSS, is there something specific that I don't know? Or is it something in my code? Is there a way to retrieve the "red" font images as well?

**EDIT 2:** OK so I narrowed it down to red HTML font in firefox being an error of some kind. If I hover over it, it says: `No space between attributes`.

Now I'm a little more confused since flickr is a huge website and it obviously still works since I see the images. Can this be some sort of "anti-scraping" thing they have going on? Is there still a way for me to download the images?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're talking about.  HTML source doesn't have colors.  It's plain text.

Comment: @recursive Sorry I should've researched more before asking. I just tried it in both IE and chrome and the text isn't red. So I'm assuming the red is simply a firefox format. However my problem as to why JSoup doesn't recognize it remains

Comment: the firefox coloring in this case just so happens to narrow down exactly what JSoup doesn't find, so it's either a coincidence, or firefox has some sort of HTML formatting based on something I don't know

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the "red" html in firefox either.  The error message suggests that there is no space between attributes, yet your code excerpt clearly shows them.  Could it be a unicode non-space character?  It doesn't appear to be amiss for me.

Comment: One problem is that the source you pasted here does not appear in the webpage you link to. And another problem is that there IS space between all the attributes in the pasted source. But indeed, red text means Firefox thinks there's an error. (The page does have errors; some `&` signs that should be `&amp;` and so on.) And no, errors are not put in websites deliberately to prevent scraping.

Comment: @MrLister The source code not being there is most likely due to the fact that flickr constantly adds photos. I edited my post to include a print screen to show everyone that I'm indeed not going insane :p

Comment: what you are looking into is Firefox saying that this is invalid HTML according to W3C standards, if you use a addon called "HTML validator" it is going to give you all the alerts & errors in detail. in this site you mentioned there is 114 errors & 41 warnings, for example, the one relate to img (your question), you can see these errors: `line 363 column 313 - Error: No space between attributes.` & `line 363 column 465 - Error: Element div not allowed as child of element a in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)` plus a border attribute obsolete warning

Comment: The warning "No space between attributes" refers to the fact that there is no space before `width` in your screenshot.  That may be causing problems for JSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I was mistaken, JSoup does indeed find ALL the `img` tags. I'm not 100% sure where my mistake was since I saw it yesterday and have changed my code since then, but I'm assuming it was my misuse of `.select` which would exclude those images (my code in this question was simplified for argument's sake).

I'll leave this question up because it might help someone else running into errored HTML in source code since there are a few helpful tips in the comments